# A scaled fractional ''Sobolev inequality''

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

Does a fractional interpolation inequality similar to $$
\int_{B_R(0)} |u| dx \le C R^{2} \sqrt{\log(2R)} \Big( \int_{\mathbb R^2}\int_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{2+2s}} dxdy + \int_{B_1(0)} |u|^2 dx \Big)^{1/2}
$$
(where $B_R(0), B_1(0) \subset \mathbb R^2$) hold? Maybe changing the powers of $R$ or of the logarithm if needed?

Is it known in the literature?

Comment: What is your choice of $s$?

Comment: @Bazin Possibly $s \in (0,1)$. Or at least $s=1/2$

Comment: Apparently you forgot the square on the left or a square root on the right (scaling in $u$ is different, as written). Which one was it?

Comment: @fedja Thanks. Square root on the right

Answer (score 2):

Then, unless there are more typos, what you request is very cheap and no logarithmic factor is needed.

WLOG, $u\ge 0$ (just consider $|u|$ instead, if not).
Denote by $A_1$ the average of $u$ over the unit disk centered at $0$ and by $A_r$ ($r=2,4,8,16,\dots$) the average of $u$ over the annulus $\frac r2\le|x|\le r$. Then, assuming that the expression in parentheses on the $RHS$ is $1$, we get $A_0\le C$ and $|A_r-A_{\frac r2}|^2 \frac {r^4}{r^{2+2s}}\le C$ (just restrict the double integration to $x\in A_{\frac r2}, y\in A_r$ and use the trivial upper bound on the denominator and Cauchy-Schwarz). Hence $|A_r-A_{\frac r2}|\le Cr^{s-1}$ and, summing a geometric progression, we get that $A_r\le C'$ for all $r$, i.e., the integral of $u$ over any disk centered at the origin is at most constant times its area.

*Edit: the details for the difference estimate*

Let $Q_r$ be the region (annulus or disk) over which $A_r$ is taken.
Then
$$
|A_r-A_{r/2}|=\frac{1}{Area(Q_r)Area(Q_{r/2})}\left|\iint_{x\in Q_r, y\in Q_{r/2}}(u(x)-u(y))\,dxdy\right|\le
\\
(2r)^{1+s}\frac{1}{Area(Q_r)Area(Q_{r/2})}\iint_{x\in Q_r, y\in Q_{r/2}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{1+s}}\,dxdy \le
\\
(2r)^{1+s}\left[\frac{1}{Area(Q_r)Area(Q_{r/2})}\iint_{x\in Q_r, y\in Q_{r/2}}\left(\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{1+s}}\right)^2\,dxdy\right]^{1/2}
\\
\le\frac{(2r)^{1+s}}{\sqrt{Area(Q_r)Area(Q_{r/2})}}\left[\iint_{x\in\mathbb R^2, y\in \mathbb R^2}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{2+2s}}\,dxdy\right]^{1/2}
$$
and it remains to note that $\sqrt{Area(Q_r)Area(Q_{r/2})}\ge cr^2$.

Comment: I don't understand what's the claim. Is it that $\int_{B_R(0)} |u|$ is bounded by a constant or that it is bounded by the right-hand side without the log?

Comment: @Jay By the right hand side without the log, of course. Otherwise it would be ridiculous: just consider $u\equiv 1$.

Comment: So the claim is  $$
\int_{B_R(0)} |u| dx \le C R^{2}  \Big( \int_{\mathbb R^2}\int_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{2+2s}} dxdy + \int_{B_1(0)} |u|^2 dx \Big)^{1/2}
$$ Is this correct? I'm not sure this holds even if we replace the fractional norm with the $H^1$ norm. In the proof you've written, where does the term $\int_{\mathbb R^2}\int_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{2+2s}} dxdy$ appear?

Comment: Yes, that's the claim. The term is used to control the difference of averages $A_r-A_{r/2}$.

Comment: @Jay And you are completely right that for $\dot {H^1}$ ($\int |\widehat f(\xi)|^2|\xi|^2d\xi<+\infty$) the logarithmic factor is needed. However, your enemy is not *high* frequencies (they integrate to small numbers anyway) but the ones close to $0$, so $\dot {H^s}$ with $0<s<1$ is a *stronger* assumption from this perspective.

Comment: Thank you. Is the power $R^2$ or $R^{s+1}$ in this case in the right hand side? Also, could you add some detail on how you get the claim starting from $|A_r - A_{r/2}| \le C r^{s-1}$?

Comment: @Jay The power reduces if you have a vanishing condition at $\infty$ but, as written, you did not exclude the identically $1$ function, so $R^2$. OK, I'll include the computation into the answer. Just wait a bit :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a bit confused: from these computations it seems that we get $R^{s}$ instead of $R^2$?

Comment: @Jay How? I'm getting that the *averages* are bounded, so the *integrals* grow as the area. What is your argument for a smaller power?